# Save value from setInterval in an array

Tags: javascript, frontend

I have a function

```
function getElapsedTime() {

    var endTime = new Date;
    var et = endTime.toLocaleTimeString();
    return et;
}

// getElapsedTime is storing only the current value from the interval
var end = window.setInterval(getElapsedTime,60000)
```

It runs every minute and gives me the current time.

I want to save the value that is being returned to an array.

**What I've tried**

```
function getElapsedTime() {
    var endList = []
    var endTime = new Date;
    var et = endTime.toLocaleTimeString();
    endList.push(et);
    return et;
}
```

Use an array to store the value `et`, but it stores the value that is being returned each minute, not the values before it.

Comment: The return value of `setInterval()` is the timer ID, which is useful for calling `clearInterval()`. You can't get the return value of the callback function, since the function runs a minute later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array needs to be a global variable. Otherwise it's reset to an empty array every time the function is called.

```
var endList = [];
function getElapsedTime() {
    var endTime = new Date;
    var et = endTime.toLocaleTimeString();
    endList.push(et);
}
```

There's no point returning `et`, since the return value of an interval function is not used for anything.